# VBA taking too long to execute

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro written that clears contents of the active cell row then calls a module to shift the remaining rows up. I am experiencing a long wait time for the macro to finish running. Not sure if this could be written better to execute quicker. The first module is called when a user clicks "Remove Client" on a User Form. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```vb
'Called when user clicks Remove Client on User Form
Sub letsgo()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("contactunder")

ws.Range("C" & ActiveCell.Row & ":BJ" & ActiveCell.Row).ClearContents

Call shiftmeup
End Sub
```

```vb
Sub shiftmeup()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("contactunder") '/// The underhood of my contacts

With ws.Range("D11:BJ392")
For i = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1
If IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 1)) Then .Rows(i).Delete Shift:=xlUp
Next
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not change this line:

```
ws.Range("C" & ActiveCell.Row & ":BJ" & ActiveCell.Row).ClearContents
```

To this:

```
ws.Range("C" & ActiveCell.Row & "BJ" & ActiveCell.Row).EntireRow.Delete
```

This way you can avoid your second sub all together (or keep this as an occasional cleaner rather run it every time you simply need to delete 1 row.)

If you really do need both subs, a common first step for efficiency is to disable screen updating before entering your loop with `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and then re-activate it when your loop ends by changing `False` to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the followup to urdearboy's answer...

The issue was in your second function and the static range used.  You were **deleting all the rows** at the end, past your data (up to ~380 extra delete row calls).  To fix it you should do two things

1. Only loop to the last row of data
2. Limit calls to the front end; put all the cells you want to delete into one range and delete it once

---

```
Sub ShiftMeUp()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim DeleteRowRange As Range
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("contactunder") '/// The underhood of my contacts

    For i = 1 To GetLastRow(1, ws)
        If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, 1)) Then Set DeleteRowRange = MakeUnion(ws.Rows(i), DeleteRowRange)
    Next
    If Not DeleteRowRange Is Nothing Then DeleteRowRange.EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End Sub
```

I used 2 on my commonly used functions to keep the code clean...

**MakeUnion**

```
Public Function MakeUnion(Arg1 As Range, Arg2 As Range) As Range
    If Arg1 Is Nothing Then
        Set MakeUnion = Arg2
    ElseIf Arg2 Is Nothing Then
        Set MakeUnion = Arg1
    Else
        Set MakeUnion = Union(Arg1, Arg2)
    End If
End Function
```

**GetLastRow**

```
Public Function GetLastRow(Optional Col As Integer = 1, Optional Sheet As Excel.Worksheet) As Long
    If Sheet Is Nothing Then Set Sheet = Application.ActiveSheet
    GetLastRow = Sheet.Cells(Sheet.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```